# Bootstrap reduce page weight

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have the following html as a banner image for a site:

```
<section>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 hidden-xs">
            <a href="/home"><img src="/images/header.jpg" alt="" width="1120" height="285" class="img-responsive"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12 visible-xs center">
            <a href="/home"><img src="/images/header-xs.jpg" alt="" width="240" height="97"></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

The large header image is 94kb.  The smaller image is 11kb.

When I use Firebug or Fiddler to see the network traffic, I see that both images are transmitted no matter what size the browser is.

Is it possible to get only the small image to transfer on xs and only the large image on non-xs and save the data transmission?

Comment: I don't think there is with Bootstrap. Need to use JS

Answer (score 3):

You could play around with CSS to load the images. (Network traffic verified to only load at media breaks)

**You will need to check for browser compatibility.**

Work OK in Chrome, Safari. Didn't try firefox. Wasn't able to get it to work in IE.

http://jsfiddle.net/w8rzp8Lv/

```
/* xs */
 @media(max-width:767px) {
    section .visible-xs img {
        content: url("http://storyacious.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/300x300.gif");
    }
}
/* sm */
 @media(min-width:768px) {
    section .hidden-xs img {
        content: url("http://socialmediaseo.net/wp-content/uploads/2010/05/500px-android-logosvg-300x300.png");
    }
}
```

2nd image doesn't load until 10 seconds after page load due to media query change.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Not without dynamically loading the image after measuring the screen size with JS. I would just use the bigger image; dynamically loading in the image in such a way would be counter productive as it would introduce its own performance concerns, and a 94kb image isn't something to be that concerned about. There are many other steps you should take to optimize the performance of your site before resorting to something like this as they will be more impactful. These steps include

1. Optimizing your images
2. GZIP all content
3. Leverage browser caching

Additionally, you can use a tool like [Googles PageSpeed Insights](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/) to see what areas can be improved.

---

However, if you must, you can use `$( window ).width();` to measure the width of the viewport and the following code to append the appriopriate image.

```
var img = $("<img />").attr('src', 'http://example/image.jpg')
    .load(function() {
        if (!this.complete || typeof this.naturalWidth == "undefined" || this.naturalWidth == 0) {
            alert('broken image!');
        } else {
            $("#something").append(img);
        }
    });
```

### Edit

If you don't mind the [patchy browser support](http://caniuse.com/#search=srcset), you can use the [`srcset`](https://css-tricks.com/responsive-images-youre-just-changing-resolutions-use-srcset/) attribute to load responsive images.

```
/*If viewport is larger than 768px, use header.jpg*/
<img src="header-xs.jpg" srcset="header.jpg 768w" alt="yah">
```

Comment: I up-voted both responses because both have good solutions/options.  I will work on a solution that uses features of both solutions.